# Flickering Li Tag on mega Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a mega menu which is currently an on click event to show a `div` called "`.mega__drop`". Which is triggered when clicking the li (main menu link eg "about us").

The click function works a treat although when its `mouseover` it flickers on and off really quickly because its being triggered by the `li` and the contents of this `li` tag are nested inside. I'm not quite sure where to go from here. any help would be much appreciated.

I would also like this to "*click and hold*" on an *ipad* to show the *mega__drop*.

[jsfiddle.net/5sdd7wLg](http://jsfiddle.net/5sdd7wLg)

```
$menu = $(".main");
$mega = $(".mega__drop");
$menu.find('li').on('click', function(evt) {
    var $this = $(evt.currentTarget);
    if ($this.find($mega).hasClass('hidden')) {
        $menu.find('.mega__drop').addClass("hidden");
        $this.find('.mega__drop').removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $this.find('.mega__drop').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="main">
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <div class="mega__drop hidden">
              <div class="grid__row">
                <div class="grid__col--6">
                  <h2>About</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A quaerat, molestiae quae, eaque inventore, sunt adipisci iure voluptas sit eos reiciendis omnis voluptates nesciunt nemo illum culpa exercitationem suscipit impedit.</p>
                  <a href="#">Discover this sections</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have created codepen..but couldn't replicate this issue...http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEEWwL

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5sdd7wLg/

Comment: Instead of mouseover, click works better. It keeps flickering because 'hidden' class keeps being added and removed while mouse movers from one to another nav link.

Comment: How would i modify what i have to support on roll over?